# How to ignore duplicate rows in CTE Select statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to ignore duplicate rows from a CTE but I am not able to do that, it seems like a CTE does not allow to use `ROWNUM()` variable to `WHERE` clause as it is showing “*Invalid column name 'numrows'*” error while trying to do so.

How do I ignore the duplicate rows while using `SELECT` in a `CTE`?

**SQL Query:**

```
DECLARE @BatchID uniqueidentifier = NEWID();
DECLARE @ClusterID SMALLINT = 1;
DECLARE @BatchSize integer = 20000;
DECLARE @myTableVariable TABLE(
    EventID BIGINT,
    HotelID int,
    BatchStatus varchar(50),
    BatchID uniqueidentifier);

WITH PendingExtResSvcEventsData_Batch AS (
    SELECT TOP (@BatchSize) t.EventID, t.HotelID, t.BatchStatus, t.BatchID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.EventID ORDER BY t.EventID) numrows 
    FROM ExtResSvcPendingMsg t WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE t.ClusterID = @ClusterID
      AND numrows = 1
      -- Exclude ExtResSvcEventID and HotelID,
      -- which are partly included in in-progress batch.
      AND NOT EXISTS (
          select 1 from ExtResSvcPendingMsg t2
          where t2.BatchStatus = 'Batched'
            and t2.EventID = t.EventID and t2.HotelID = t.HotelID
          )
    )
UPDATE PendingExtResSvcEventsData_Batch
   SET BatchStatus='Batched',
       BatchID = @BatchID
OUTPUT INSERTED.* INTO @myTableVariable --WHERE numrows = 1

SELECT e.ExtResSvcEventID, e.HotelID, e.ID1, e.ID2, e.ExtResSvcEventType, e.HostID,
       e.StatusCode, e.ChannelID, e.RequestAtTime, e.ProcessTime, e.DateBegin, e.DateEnd,
       e.StatusMsg, em.MsgBodyOut, em.MsgBodyIn, e.ChannelResID 
FROM  ExtResSvcEvent e WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN @myTableVariable t ON e.ExtResSvcEventID = t.EventID
INNER JOIN ExtResSvcEventXML em WITH (NOLOCK) ON t.EventID = em.ExtResSvcEventID
ORDER BY e.ExtResSvcEventID
```

Comment: 'It seems like a CTE does not allow to use ROWNUM() variable to where clause'. Nothing allows you to do this, not just a CTE. You seem to have a bit of a CTE obsession. Why?

Comment: CTE is new for me and I am struggling using it in my query, Can you please advise better approach or suggest changes in my SQL query?

Comment: Don't use ROW_NUMBER() in WHERE clause in your CTE, but in WHERE clause of UPDATE statement.

Comment: @AdamLuniewski: `OUTPUT INSERTED.*` doesn't allow using `WHERE` Clause in an `UPDATE` statement.. I had tried that before and it was showing `incorrect syntax error`.

Comment: Did you try `UPDATE .. SET .. WHERE .. OUTPUT ...;`?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: yes, i have tried that and it gives error - `The column reference "inserted.numrows" is not allowed because it refers to a base table that is not being modified in this statement.`

Comment: What's the primary key of  `ExtResSvcPendingMsg`? It would help if you added more details in the question, about what you are trying to do exactly and the tables' definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would expect this to work but without table definitions, we can't be sure:

```
WITH 
PendingExtResSvcEventsData_Batch 
   (...),                           -- your CTE here
upd AS
  ( SELECT EventID, HotelID, BatchStatus, BatchID 
    FROM PendingExtResSvcEventsData_Batch 
    WHERE numrows = 1
  )
UPDATE upd
SET BatchStatus = 'Batched',  
    BatchID = @BatchID
OUTPUT INSERTED.* INTO @myTableVariable ;
```

A simplified test at: **[dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=23bb3eb55cd88acdb50ce20ab7cef956)**

There are more issues with the query though:

- What's the reason behind using `NOLOCK` hint? I suggest you remove it, unless you have a reason for that - and you have read about the consequences and accept the behaviour.
- You have `SELECT TOP (@BatchSize)` without a specific `ORDER BY`. That means that arbitrary rows will be selected to be returned by that subquery.
- Combined with the `WHERE numrows = 1` that you want to apply in the next step, it means that the update may affect fewer rows than the specified `@Batchsize`, possibly even just one.

Answer (score 5):

Do not use `INSERTED.*` here:

```
OUTPUT INSERTED.* INTO @myTableVariable
```

Instead, list the columns explicitly:

```
OUTPUT INSERTED.EventID,
       INSERTED.HotelID,
       INSERTED.BatchStatus,
       INSERTED.BatchID
INTO @myTableVariable
```

The `*` means all the columns of the target dataset. The target dataset in your case is a CTE which, apart from normal columns, returns a calculated column. The `INSERTED.*` syntax includes the calculated column too but referencing a calculated column is not allowed in that context. Listing all the required columns explicitly resolves the issue.

And you *can* use the `numrows` filter on that UPDATE (but not inside the CTE). The `numrows` reference will be valid everywhere apart from the OUTPUT clause and on the left side of an assignment in the SET clause.

[Here is a demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=14c53c5b5233b2f7a913f3f248ef2c3f), which shamelessly borrows ypercubeᵀᴹ's setup as well as his UPDATE statement.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `nolock` here

`PARTITION BY t.EventID ORDER BY t.EventID` is going to be an arbitrary order.  Are you sure that is what you want.

`top` without and order by is `arbitrary`. You are partially batching but then you exclude partial batches. This seems wrong to me.

You can just use `numrows` in the final select.

```
DECLARE @BatchID uniqueidentifier = NEWID();
DECLARE @ClusterID SMALLINT = 1;
DECLARE @BatchSize integer = 20000;
DECLARE @myTableVariable TABLE(EventID BIGINT,HotelID int, BatchStatus varchar(50),BatchID uniqueidentifier);

WITH PendingExtResSvcEventsData_Batch AS
(  SELECT TOP (@BatchSize) t.EventID, t.HotelID, t.BatchStatus, t.BatchID
       ,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.EventID ORDER BY t.EventID) numrows 
     FROM ExtResSvcPendingMsg t  
    WHERE t.ClusterID = @ClusterID 
      AND numrows = 1 
      AND NOT EXISTS ( select 1 
                         from ExtResSvcPendingMsg t2 
                        where t2.BatchStatus = 'Batched' 
                          and t2.EventID = t.EventID 
                          and t2.HotelID = t.HotelID       
                      )
)        
UPDATE PendingExtResSvcEventsData_Batch 
   SET BatchStatus = 'Batched',  
       BatchID = @BatchID
OUTPUT INSERTED.* INTO @myTableVariable --WHERE numrows = 1

SELECT e.ExtResSvcEventID, e.HotelID, e.ID1, e.ID2, e.ExtResSvcEventType, e.HostID, e.StatusCode, e.ChannelID, e.RequestAtTime, e.ProcessTime, e.DateBegin, e.DateEnd, e.StatusMsg, em.MsgBodyOut, em.MsgBodyIn, e.ChannelResID 
  FROM ExtResSvcEvent e WITH (NOLOCK) 
 INNER JOIN @myTableVariable t 
    ON e.ExtResSvcEventID = t.EventID    
   AND t.numrows = 1 
 INNER JOIN ExtResSvcEventXML em with (nolock) 
    on t.EventID = em.ExtResSvcEventID            
 ORDER BY e.ExtResSvcEventID
```

Why output all rows.  It looks like you are only using t.EventID.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions I have made those changes and Got 2 errors while testing this query ...

Msg 404, Level 16, State 1, Line 6

 `The column reference "inserted.numrows" is not allowed because it refers to a base table that is not being modified in this statement.`


Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
`Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.`

Comment: Then you should have had those errors all along as I changed nothing there.  This is just confusing and appears you have not thought this through.  Sorry I could not have been of more assistance.

Comment: The Select inside the CTE statement having rownum column which  you advised to use in final select clause but the numrows is not inserting in @myTableVariable. Its showing error 

i.e. `The column reference "inserted.numrows" is not allowed because it refers to a base table that is not being modified in this statement.` OUTPUT Inserted.* INTO @myTableVariable 


not allowing rownum to insert to @myTableVariable hope this helps to clarify the issue.

Comment: Not me advising that.  That is and was in YOUR query.  You should have been getting those errors all along.   This is just a sloppy query that you did not test.   I chose not to spend any more time on it.